# php file upload array sum

Tags: javascript, php, upload, directory

hey I keep getting the error

> array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks a ton. I think i may have a slash in the wrong spot on a folder name or something? I have a drop down menu giving me the value for the folder and am submitting my form through javascript like so:

```
document.getElementById("form").submit();
alert("form submitted");
```

PHP

```
<?php
$type = $_POST['Folder'];
$folder = "uploaded/$type";
$allow_types=array("aiff","mp3","wav");
$max_combined_size="10000";

If($_POST['submit']==true) {

    //Tally the size of all the files uploaded, check if it's over the ammount. 
    If(array_sum($_FILES['file']['size']) > $max_combined_size*1024) {

        echo "Combined file size is to large";

        / Loop though, verify and upload files.
    } Else {
        // Loop through all the files.
        For($i=0; $i <= $file_uploads-1; $i++) {
            //Get the file extension
            $file_ext[$i] = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            // If the file is a file
            If($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]) {
                // Randomize file names

                $file_name[$i]=1;
                while(1){
                    $file_name[$i] =$file_name[$i]+1;
                    if exists("$folder/$file_name[$i].$file_ext[$i]")){ 
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // Check for blank file name
                If(str_replace(" ", "", $file_name[$i])=="") {      
                    echo " Blank file name detected";
                } ElseIf(!in_array($file_ext[$i], $allow_types)) {
                    echo "Invalide file type";
                } Elseif(file_exists($folder.$file_name[$i].".".$file_ext[$i])) {

                    echo "File already exists";

                } Else {

                    If(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],$folder.$file_name[$i].".".$file_ext[$i])) {
                        echo "success!";    
                    } Else {
                        echo "upload failure";
                    }
                }
            } // If Files
        } // For
    } // Else Total Size 
}
?>
```

Comment: `array_sum()` only works with one dimensional arrays

Comment: `array_sum()` would work if you had multiple form inputs for multiple files, so you would have to have `<input type="file" name="file[]" />`.

Answer (score 0):

You call `array_sum`, pass in a value, which is not an array. The value you pass is `$_FILES['file']['size']`, which is not an array, but just the (integer) size of the file 'file'.

Unfortunately, you want to sum the sizes, but they are nested deeper in the files array. The files array itself contains arrays for each item, and each item is an array with keys that contain the various properties of one file. The function can only sum the items of a single, one dimensional array, so the function isn't going to help much here.

Solve it using a loop instead:

```
$size = 0;
foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
  $size += $file['size'];
}

if ($size > $max_combined_size*1024) {
  .. Do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
array_sum($_FILES['file']['size'])
```

Is your problem, array_sum is expecting an array, but you're sending it a size. Size is probably an integer. Try

```
array_sum($_FILES['file'])
```

and see if you get a different error.

Comment: You probably won't get an error, but also no good result, since you're just trying to sum all properties of the file, like its name, type, and so on. So this answer is not very helpful.